# UDIMM Ram is same as SD-RAM?

Tags: memory

Little lost finding memory for a server. I need 2x4GBs that match the following:

2GB (1x2GB) or 4GB (1x4GB) of PC3-10600E DDR3 UDIMM

But the closest I found on newegg for example was Kingston 4GB 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM ECC Unbuffered DDR3 1333 (PC3 10600) Server Memory Intel Model KVR13E9/4I

Are they the same?

Answer (score 3):

UDIMM just means unregistered, so you don't have to get [registered memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory) (required on some servers).  There are excellent sites out there (including [Kingston's own memory finder](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/mfrmod.asp)) that will give you a list of compatible sticks when you plug in the server or motherboard model number.  For a specific model, and if you are unsure, they are a great help.

With that said, unregistered memory is the most common, and as long as the pin count and rating is the same you will usually be fine, whether it is "approved" or not.  When you have to be absolutely sure (think critical path server where you want vendor support), you go the approved route.  For home or less critical use, you can take more of a "risk"

Comment: @Ramhound laptops use SO-DIMM

Answer (score 3):

> UDIMM Ram is same as SD-RAM?

No. DIMM is merely a form factor.

DIMMs come with a variety of memory on them, the most common ones are:

- SDRAM of type DDR3, **u**nbufffered. 64 bit wide.
- SDRAM of type DDR3, bufffered / registered (both names mean the same thing)
- SDRAM of type DDR3, **u**nbufffered. 72 bit wide (64 bit + ECC)
- SDRAM of type DDR3, bufffered / registered, 72 bit wide (64 bit + ECC)

The last is mostly used in servers, the first in consumer devices.

There is slightly more to it, since there are also low voltage versions, and DIMMs can have different ranks. Usually you do not need to worry about this and can just buy the cheapest (often rank 2) modules.

If your server has multiple CPU's (as in, actual multiple chips in multiple sockets, not one CPU with multiple cores) then you might need to fill the memory banks on both CPU's.

If you want to enable multiple memory channels (e.g. dual-channel, triple channel, quad channel) for a slight speed boost (roughly 5% for dual channel), then you will need to use similar modules on the same memory channel.

For any more concrete answers you will need to add more details to your post. Such as which server model. Which CPU(s) are used. How are the memory banks filled? What is the goal? (e.g. add more RAM, add fastest RAM, cheapest ways to add RAM, ...)

Answer (score 0):

@ Jack Willis,

Could you be more specific about the model number of your server and the specifications of the memory which you have installed in your server??

Btw, the memory which you have found in the Newegg.com matches the specification PC3-10600E DDR3 UDIMM and it should be compatible with your server. Make sure that you are not mixing Registered ECC with Unbuffered ECC (unregistered ECC) and vice-versa. Make sure the type of memory ranks your server supports per channel. Please refer your manual before you make the purchase. If you have any queries then let me know ... i'll be happy to assist you with the same?

Comment: If you want to request clarification, leave a comment on the question. You already have enough reputation to do so. Please edit your answer.